# Streaming string from asp.net core without the square brackets?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, stream, jsonstream

The index function in my HomeController:

```
   public IEnumerable<string> Index()
   {
       foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
       {
           yield return "Test: " + i;

           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }
   }
```

The idea is that when visiting the Index "Test: i" will be printed every second.

However it doesn't work very well, the output comes in small blocks rather than in a timed fashion, so the page is stuck being retrieved then I get a block of responses but it's very very slow.

The output also has square brackets, I think this is because I'm returning an IEnumerable type so I was wondering if there was a different way to do this? I'm trying to mimic a http stream which doesn't have square brackets.

Comment: put 1000 instead of 100 ;)

Comment: @DIe oh dear, I edited my question. Still doesn't work sadly but now the problem is different :(

Comment: *The output also has square brackets* - did you ever heard of JSON? http://json.org